# Creating a scheduled task that runs on 6 days a week

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0, comobject

I'm trying to create a few scheduled tasks using PowerShell prior to the `TaskScheduler` module, which is not an option as this will be used to run a process on external client machines. Therefore I can't use cmd as I need to specify the credentials each time.

I have delved into the comobject a little but I don't really understand this.
I would be more than happy to use this if I could figure out the triggers, basically I need it to run 6 days a week (excluding Sunday) at a specific time once a day.

I think ive got the action and arguments down but it's the trigger im struggling with understanding.

This is the block im working on which was liberated from [here](https://ryanschlagel.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/managing-scheduled-tasks-with-powershell/), so all credit there!

```
try {
    [Object] $objScheduledTask = New-Object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")

    if (!($objScheduledTask.Connected)) {
        try {
            $objScheduledTask.Connect($env:COMPUTERNAME)
            $objScheduledTask_Folder = $objScheduledTask.GetFolder('\')
            $objScheduledTask_TaskDefinition = $objScheduledTask.NewTask(0)

            #Registration / Definitions
            $objScheduledTask_RegistrationInfo = $objScheduledTask_TaskDefinition.RegistrationInfo
            $objScheduledTask_RegistrationInfo.Description = 'My task name'

            #Define Settings
            $objScheduledTask_Settings = $objScheduledTask_TaskDefinition.Settings
            $objScheduledTask_Settings.Enabled = $True
            $objScheduledTask_Settings.StartWhenAvailable = $True
            $objScheduledTask_Settings.Hidden = $False

            #Triggers
            $objScheduledTask_Triggers = $objScheduledTask_TaskDefinition.Triggers
            $objScheduledTask_Trigger = $objScheduledTask_Triggers.Create(2)
            $objScheduledTask_Trigger.StartBoundary = "2011-10-01T04:00:00"
            $objScheduledTask_Trigger.DaysInterval = 1
            $objScheduledTask_Trigger.Id = "DailyTriggerId"
            $objScheduledTask_Trigger.Enabled = $True

            #Action
            $objScheduledTask_Action = $objScheduledTask_TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
            $objScheduledTask_Action.Path = 'task\to\execute.exe'
            $objScheduledTask_Action.Arguments = ''
            $objScheduledTask_Action.WorkingDirectory = 'C:\'

            #Create Task
            $objScheduledTask_Folder.RegisterTaskDefinition('Sample Scheduled Task Description', $objScheduledTask_TaskDefinition, 6, "System", $null , 5) | out-null
            Write-Host "Scheduled Task Created Successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
        } catch [System.Exception] {
            Write-Host "Scheduled Task Creation Failed" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
} catch [System.Exception]{
    Write-Host "Scheduled Task Creation Failed" -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host "  EXCEPTION:" $_ -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [weekly trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa384054%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of a daily trigger if you want to run a task on selected days per week. The [`DaysOfWeek` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa384024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifies the days as a bitmask in an integer value.

```
$objScheduledTask_Triggers = $objScheduledTask_TaskDefinition.Triggers
$objScheduledTask_Trigger = $objScheduledTask_Triggers.Create(3)
$objScheduledTask_Trigger.StartBoundary = '2011-10-01T04:00:00'
$objScheduledTask_Trigger.WeeksInterval = 1  # run every week
$objScheduledTask_Trigger.DaysOfWeek = 126   # Mo-Sa
$objScheduledTask_Trigger.Id = 'DailyTriggerId'
$objScheduledTask_Trigger.Enabled = $true
```

Comment: Sorry i thought i had clicked it! :D